# Reflection and Subclass

Tags: c#, reflection, subclass

I have code

```
public static class A {
    public static class B { }
    public static class C { }
}
```

Am I using the reflection class A to find out what it contains subclasses? How to find out the subclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which are not called *subclasses* but **nested classes**. Have a look at [Type.GetNestedTypes method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/493t6h7t.aspx); it's easy to do.

```
var nestedTypes=typeof(A).GetNestedTypes();
```